# Pandas Count of Employees by Quarter and Company

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I have two very, very large pandas dataframes.

[image: df_A]

df_A has one row for each YearQuarter and Company

[image: df_B]

df_B has one row for each distinct employee

I want to count the number of employees that are employed for each company each quarter. An employee is counted as employed in a quarter if their StartYearQuarter <= YearQuarter and EndYearQuarter >= YearQuarter.

I have tried a variety of different approaches so far but they have all ran into memory issues, or returned incorrect results, as the dataframes are so large.

Here is an example of one bit of code I ran which told me I would need 160GBi of free RAM when ran in Jupyter and just crashed my Azure Python Kernel:

```py
merged = pd.merge(df_A, df_B, on="Company Name")
employed = merged_df[(merged_df['StartYearQuarter'] <= merged_df['YearQuarter']) & (merged_df['EndYearQuarter'] >= merged_df['YearQuarter'])]
result = employed.groupby(['YearQuarter', 'Company Name']).size().reset_index(name='Employee Count')
```

Is there a more memory efficient way of counting the number of employees for each Company by YearQuarter?

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Please don't share pictures of data, that is not producible for us. Now we have to make our own dataframe

Answer (score 1):

If you use the pyspark,

```
data1 = [['1997Q3', 'test1'], ['1997Q4', 'test1']]
data2 = [['test1', '1997Q2', '1998Q1', 1], ['test1', '1997Q3', '1997Q3', 2]]

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data1, ['YearQuarter', 'Company Name'])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, ['Company Name2', 'StartYearQuarter', 'EndYearQuarter', 'ID'])

df1.show()
df2.show()

df1.join(df2, (f.col('Company Name') == f.col('Company Name2')) & f.col('YearQuarter').between(f.col('StartYearQuarter'), f.col('EndYearQuarter')), 'inner') \
  .groupBy('Company Name', 'YearQuarter') \
  .count() \
  .show()

+-----------+------------+
|YearQuarter|Company Name|
+-----------+------------+
|     1997Q3|       test1|
|     1997Q4|       test1|
+-----------+------------+

+-------------+----------------+--------------+---+
|Company Name2|StartYearQuarter|EndYearQuarter| ID|
+-------------+----------------+--------------+---+
|        test1|          1997Q2|        1998Q1|  1|
|        test1|          1997Q3|        1997Q3|  2|
+-------------+----------------+--------------+---+

+------------+-----------+-----+
|Company Name|YearQuarter|count|
+------------+-----------+-----+
|       test1|     1997Q3|    2|
|       test1|     1997Q4|    1|
+------------+-----------+-----+
```